# how to choose the right action to implement the logic business

Tags: struts2, action

Suppose I have three entities.

- Department
- Task
- User

User can publish some Task belonging to his Departments. He can belong to more than one Department.

The relationships of the three entities are:

```
User---Task----many2many
User-Department --Many2many
Task--Department -- many2one
```

I use Hibernate and I set all of the associations as bidirectional.

Now I have some requirements:

1. List all the tasks that belong to a specified user (the tasks this user published).
2. List all the tasks that belong to user's department (if this user belong to dep1 and dep2, now I should list all the tasks of the dep1 and dep2).
3. List all the tasks of a department.
4. List all the tasks of all the departments.

These logic codes are not difficult, but where do I put these logics? to the UserAction or TaskAction or DepartmentAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Rest plug-in, then it might make sense in general to have a `DepartmentAction`, `TaskAction`, and `UserAction`, but you don't need to limit yourself to all-encompassing actions like those.

From your description, it sounds to me like the four requirements are all really one action that lists tasks by various criteria. Therefore, I would create a single action called `ListTasksAction`. This action would take parameters to indicate which of the four criteria to limit on.

You could also create separate actions for the four requirements (perhaps with a shared interface or abstract class).